# Very blurry font rendering in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: fonts

Here is a screenshot from my terminal:

[image]

Black on yellow is fine. Yellow on dark is a little bad and black on red is absolutely terrible. I am using a 4k screen, 60Hz, 100% scaling. Font is Ubuntu Mono.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your screenshot. Does your screen look different?  Are you sure you are using the screen's native resolution?

Comment: I can see a little blur compared to the surrounding text in your question. But it is difficult to tell if it is caused at your screen or because of fractional scaling when displaying/zooming the image when rendered by AskUbuntu or by my Firefox. Anyway, like @Nmath, I suggest that you check carefully, that you use the screen's native resolution (and 100 % scaling). -- But if you notice differences in blur depending on the colours, I think you should blame the hardware in the screen or your eyes, and not Ubuntu or the graphics driver.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking at the screenshot on another computer now and it looks fine. Must be an issue very late in the pipeline to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshot only looks bad on the affected computer. May be a hardware issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know :-)